# Does the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}B_{(4k-2)}+B_{(4k)}$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, divergent-series, bernoulli-numbers

Just as the title says I'd like to know if this sum
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(B_{(4k-2)}+B_{(4k)})
$$
converges and if so to which value. Here $B_{2k}$ are Bernoulli numbers.

I've tried with Mathematica but it seems inconclusive.

Thanks.

---

**EDIT:**
Meanwhile I found this related question: [What is sum of the Bernoulli numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/536678/what-is-sum-of-the-bernoulli-numbers)
.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Bernoulli_numbers_and_the_Riemann_zeta_function),

$$
|B_{2 n}|\sim4\sqrt{\pi n}\left(\frac n{\pi\mathrm e}\right)^{2n}
$$

as $n\to\infty$. It follows that $B_{4k-2}+B_{4k}$ doesn't go to zero as $k\to\infty$, so the series diverges.